# Xamarin + sqlite: Trouble reading database

Tags: android, database, visual-studio, sqlite, xamarin

I am opening a database file, and running select * query and no objects are found. I have:

1. Created a DB in DB Browser for SQLite, stored the db file in common project, as well as assets/resources for Droid/iOS with proper Build Action (AndroidAsset/BundleResource)
2. Created interface in common code and DatabaseService in Droid:

   ```
   public SQLiteConnection CreateConnection()
   {
       var sqliteFilename = "StepsDatabase.db";
       string documentsDirectoryPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
       var path = Path.Combine(documentsDirectoryPath, sqliteFilename);

       var conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path);

       //conn.CreateTable<Step>();
       //conn.CreateTable<SuperStep>();

       return conn;
   }
   ```

   (I have tried with and without the .CreateTable as I saw that was a possible solution from another question)
3. Created C# mdoels for both tables in my database

```
namespace StepsDB
{
    [Table("Step")]
    public class Step
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Unique, Column("stepID")]
        public int stepID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [NotNull, Column("name")]
        public string name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [NotNull, Column("superStep")]
        public int superStep
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Column("videoLocation")]
        public string videoLocation
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Column("uploader")]
        public string uploader
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Column("uploaderIG")]
        public string uploaderIG
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

4. Created a DatabaseManager that calls CreateConnection() and then a select * query from both tables and empty Lists are created.

Even when I debug and check the "conn" variable, it has TableMappings Count = 0.

PS using sqlite-net-pcl NuGet installed in all projects.

I have been stuck on this for a LONG time and have scoured the internet but no solution that worked for others have worked for me. Please help!

Also this is my first question so if I have done anything wrong please let me know.

Comment: you are creating an empty db because the path you are using does not match the location (resources/assets) where you are storing your pre-created db.  If you intend to write to your db, you will need to copy it to a user writable folder on app startup.

Comment: I am only intending to read from it. I have checked the path it creates and looked in the device monitor and it was in that location. I also checked File.Exists(path), which returns true.

Comment: SQLite will create a new dB if one does not already exist.    So file.exists may not actually be useful.  You need to read up on how to use android assets

Comment: Do you have any resources or links? Everything I’ve read and every example I’ve seen has that assets will be in that path. Thank you.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-assets?tabs=windows

Comment: Wow I feel pretty silly after realizing the problem. Guess I'm a little rusty with programming in general. Thanks for the help - I am now reading my database properly! Woohoo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never properly opening my database asset, only creating an empty file. I now use

```
var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.Open(sqliteFilename))
```

to open the asset and write it to the file location I was trying to open originally. Once I create the connection it properly maps to my objects and I have a list to use! :) :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use EF Core to access Sqlite databases easily.

use this command to install EFCore Sqlite package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
```

Then you can use EFCore standard functions to create databases at runtime.